# Handling multi-line headers and hidden columns with F# ExcelProvider

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am trying to parse and excel file using Excel Provider an example of this is shown below.

```
type Data = {
     Time: string
     Pressure: string
     Force: string
     Appshear: string
     Stress: string
     Appvisc: string
     Shear: string
     Viscosity: string
     Position: string
     Temperature: string
     Velocity: string
     Fgamr: string
     M: string}

open FSharp.Interop.Excel
type TheFile = ExcelFile<"************.xls","Data",HasHeaders =false>
let file = TheFile()
let rows = file.Data 
       |> Seq.skip 3
       |> Seq.head
```

The first row consists of the output shown below.

```
val rows : ExcelFile<...>.Row =
Row 3
    Column1 =
    Column10 = [Pa*s]
    Column11 = [mm]
    Column12 = [°C]
    Column13 = [°C]
    Column14 = [°C]
    Column15 = [mm/s]
    Column16 = [-]
    Column17 = [-]
    Column18 =
    Column19 =
    Column2 = [hh:mm:ss.00]
    Column20 =
    Column21 =
    Column22 =
    Column23 =
    Column24 =
    Column25 =
    Column26 =
    Column27 =
    Column28 =
    Column29 =
    Column3 = [bar]
    Column4 = [N]
    Column5 = [1/s]
    Column6 = [Pa]
    Column7 = [Pa*s]
    Column8 = [1/s]
    Column9 = [Pa]
```

How do I take these row outputs and put them into the record to save as a .csv?

Comment: What do you mean? You already have them, as properties of the row elements. In the code you posted though, `rows` is produced by `Seq.head` which means it's a single row, not a sequence of rows

Comment: How would I call Column1 for example?

Comment: Have you tried `rows.Column1` ? ExcelProvider exposes the *sheet's data as a type*, it doesn't parse it using your own custom type. If heades are available, they are used as the field names for the row type.

Comment: The headers are all messed up and hidden so not all of the rows are collected. Therefore, I have to put HasHeaders to false. Are you talking about adding this pip in here? |> Seq.map ( fun rows -> rows.Column2)

Comment: Would you know how to parse out this data?

Comment: The question is unclear - Excel isn't a text file that needs parsing. The data is *already* parsed, and can be used as is or exported to CSV directly. Is the real question how to handle headers perhaps? What does the Excel file look like? You may be able to skip any unwanted rows or columns by specifying the Range parameter

Comment: If you check [the unit tests in Github](https://github.com/fsprojects/ExcelProvider/blob/master/tests/ExcelProvider.Tests/ExcelProvider.Tests.fs#L12) you'll see you can specify disjointed regions with the `Range` parameter. By specifying eg `Range="A2"` you can skip the first row and start reading from column A in the second row

Comment: You should post an example of the sheet, but judging from the first row's contents it looks like there's a multi-row header including names and units, perhaps even merged cells? And hidden columns after column 19? You may be able to handle this with `Range` or you may have have to use different ExcelProvider types to read different sections. One can only guess without knowing what the file looks like